# Onclick handler for dynamic button (added via JS) returning null

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener

I have a `button`, in my markup called `.open-video`.

Clicking `.open-video` opens up a modal which then contains another button `.close--modal`. The code for the modal (which includes the markup for `.modal--close`) is added when the `.open-video` button is clicked.

Now, I'm aware that the `EventListener` for `.modal--close` needs to exist **after** the markup is added to the `DOM` on the first `EventListener` for `.open-video`. But, doing this isn't doing anything at the moment, I instead get the error message `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')` and I believe this is because the `DOMContentLoaded` event was already fired at this point.

Currently, when clicking `.modal--close`, I just want to do a simple `console.log("test");`.

**See my demo below:**

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  ready();
} else {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
}

function ready() {

  let video_btn = document.querySelector(".open-video");
  let close_btn = document.querySelector(".modal--close");
  let modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

  console.log(close_btn);

  if (video_btn) {
    video_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      // get data
      var triggerURL = this.getAttribute("href");
      var triggerID = this.getAttribute("data-modal");

      // update modal attributes  with trigger data
      modal.setAttribute("data-video", triggerURL);
      modal.setAttribute("id", triggerID);

      var modalID = '#' + triggerID;
      modal.classList.add("modal--open");

      var html = '<a href="#" class="modal--close"></a><div class="modal__wrapper"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="' + triggerURL + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div class="modal__overlay"></div>';

      // modal.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
      modal.innerHTML = html;

      close_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("test");
      });

      return false;

    });

  }

}
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  padding: 70px 80px;
}

.modal--close {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
  top: 32px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 999999;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}

.modal--close:hover:before,
.modal--close:hover:after {
  background-color: #F15A40;
}

.modal--close:before,
.modal--close:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.modal--close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.modal--close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.modal--open {
  display: block;
}

.modal .modal__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 150;
}

.modal .modal__wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.modal .modal__wrapper iframe,
.modal .modal__wrapper video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
}

.modal .modal__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<a class="button--play open-video" data-modal="video--1" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpEaa2P7qZI">Click me</a>

<div class="videoModal modal modal__post--modal">
  <div class="modal__wrapper"></div>
  <div class="modal__overlay"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get my `.modal--close` button to print the log? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In your JS and CSS you are targeting `modal--close` but the class in your HTML is `modal__close`.

Comment: @Jack - Sorry, ignore the `. modal__close` in the markup (I've removed it from the question). That was me testing another approach, which didn't work.

Comment: Move your close button selector to after you have injected the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Because you call `closeElement` before you create `closeElement`. 
You can call this element after creating.

```
video_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    
    // ... codes
  
    // modal.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    modal.innerHTML = html;
    let close_btn = document.querySelector(".modal--close");
    close_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("test");
    });

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't document.querySelect an element before it's added to the DOM, you should move the line of

```
let close_btn = document.querySelector(".modal--close"); // here
```

to inside the video_btn.addEventListener callback function after you've added the element `.modal--close` to the DOM.

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  ready();
} else {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
}

function ready() {

  let video_btn = document.querySelector(".open-video");
  let modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

  if (video_btn) {
    video_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      // get data
      var triggerURL = this.getAttribute("href");
      var triggerID = this.getAttribute("data-modal");

      // update modal attributes  with trigger data
      modal.setAttribute("data-video", triggerURL);
      modal.setAttribute("id", triggerID);

      var modalID = '#' + triggerID;
      modal.classList.add("modal--open");

      var html = '<a href="#" class="modal--close"></a><div class="modal__wrapper"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="' + triggerURL + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div class="modal__overlay"></div>';

      // modal.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
      modal.innerHTML = html;
      let close_btn = document.querySelector(".modal--close"); // here

      close_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("test");
      });

      return false;

    });

  }

}
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  padding: 70px 80px;
}

.modal--close {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
  top: 32px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 999999;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}

.modal--close:hover:before,
.modal--close:hover:after {
  background-color: #F15A40;
}

.modal--close:before,
.modal--close:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.modal--close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.modal--close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.modal--open {
  display: block;
}

.modal .modal__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 150;
}

.modal .modal__wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.modal .modal__wrapper iframe,
.modal .modal__wrapper video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
}

.modal .modal__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<a class="button--play open-video" data-modal="video--1" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpEaa2P7qZI">Click me</a>

<div class="videoModal modal modal__post--modal">
  <div class="modal__wrapper"></div>
  <div class="modal__overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if the code snippet did not show you the console logs, you can see them in your browser's dev tools. ignoring the other errors as they're part of the StackOverflow itself, not a part of your code